# How to include zip content in Spring-Boot project's classpath using gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Hi fellow software engineers,

I have the following situation.
At this moment, I have a spring-boot project with a bundled web app (React) whose built source files are stored under `resources/static` directory.

Basically the file structure looks something like this:

```
main
|----java
|    |---
|---resources
|    |---static
|        |---static
|            |---css,js...
|        |---index.html
|        |---...
|    |---otherResources
```

We've come to a point where we uploaded the web-app, in the form of a `zip` file on Nexus.

`groupId: my.project / artifactId: my-web-app / version: 1.0 / ext: zip`

```
my-web-app-1.0.zip
|---static
    |---css,js...
|---index.html
|---...
```

Now I want to remove the duplicated files from my repository (resources) and *replace* them with the content of the zip file.

I'm not sure how can I achieve this using spring-boot and **gradle** and I would like some guidance please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get to the same exact structure I did something like this:

`build.gradle`

```
configurations {
   webAppZip
}

dependencies {
   // other dependencies
   webAppZip(group: 'my.project', name: 'my-web-app', version: 1.0, ext: 'zip')
}

task unzip(type: Copy) {
    var webAppLocation = "src/main/resources/static"
    delete webAppLocation
    from zipTree(configurations.webAppZip.singleFile)
    into webAppLocation
}

processResources {
    dependsOn(unzip)
}
```

Additionally one can add the `static` directory to `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

You must load zip and unzip , then replace source:

```
main {
    resources {
        srcDir 'src'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider writing 'have to' instead of 'must'. Must has an ethical meaning in English.